# Can hide Terminator but can't show it again?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, windows-subsystem-for-linux, terminator, vcxsrv

I've written a short script to start `vcxsrv` then run `bash -c -l "DISPLAY=:0 terminator"` and after a moment the terminal launches, however when I toggle the `hide_window` hotkey in `terminator` (I've customized it to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>, but the default doesn't work either) it will hide the terminal, but the same key combination will not show the terminal unless an x11 app is active on the screen.

Is there any way to send <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> to `vcxsrv` to show my terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure `xdotool` is installed in your system

```
sudo apt-get install -y xdotool
```

Then create an [autohotkey](http://autohotkey.com) script:

```
^`::
    Run, bash -c "DISPLAY=:0 xdotool key ctrl+grave", , Hide
Return
```

this captures the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> and replays it to the X server through a hidden bash window.

Comment: For whatever reason using `Hide` doesn't work for me. I'm guessing it has something to do with stdio/interactive, but `Min` works and it's only a slight flicker that I'm fine with dealing with. `Run,bash.exe -c "DISPLAY=:0 xdotool key ctrl+grave",,Min`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick *ad hoc* measure:

While your Terminator window *A* is hidden start up a new Terminator window *B*. In window *B*, hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> if you still have the default keybinding for `hide_window`). This should toggle visiblity on *both* windows, with the result that *A* is visible and *B* is hidden.

(You might clean up *B* with `kill` if you cared to do so.)